# How would you interpret this sentence "見える人にだけ見える光だ"?

Tags: grammar, parsing, song-lyrics

It was excerpted from the lyrics of amazarashi's song called "未来になれなかったあの夜に."

I tried to interpret "見える人" as the subject and "見える人にだけ見える" wholly as an adjectival clause; semantically, it sounds good and fits my feeling about the song: "A lonely person was standing or walking in the light of a late-night, there was me and the light and probably my shadow"; but grammatically, it sounds a bit odd.

Any ideas? though artists sometimes are free from any grammatical restraint.

Here are the full lyrics:

「色々あったな」の 色々の一つ一つを

つまびらかにしたくて ペンを取ったわけですが

もう君の好きにしてよ 僕も大概好きにしてきた

僕の事は忘れて 他に行きたい場所があるんなら

名誉ある潔い撤退より 泥にまみれ無様な前進を

尻尾を振る称賛の歌より 革命の最中響く怒号を

あの日の情熱の火はいずこ 悔しさを並べたプレイリスト

そぞろリピート音楽と風景 後悔、浄化する過去の巡礼

まさかお前、生き別れたはずの 青臭い夢か？恐れ知らずの

酒のつまみの思い出話と 成り下がるには眩しすぎたよ

なじられたなら怒ってもいいよ 一人で泣けば誰にもバレないよ

そんな夜達に「ほら見たろ？」って 無駄じゃなかったと抱きしめたいよ

未来になれなかった あの夜に

前向きに生きることほど素晴らしいことはない

でも「前向きに生きて」じゃ 頷けない誰かさんの為

夢追い人とは ともすれば社会の孤児だ

手段は選ばない いや、選べなかったんだ

恨み辛みや妬み嫉みの グラフキューブで心根を塗った

それでも尚塗りつぶせなかった 余白の部分が己と知った

今更弱さ武器にはしないよ それが僕らがやってきたことの

正しさの証明と知っている 今この僕があの日の答えだ

**見える人にだけ見える光だ　陰こそ唯一光の理解者**

旅立ちと言えば聞こえはいいが 全部投げ出して逃げ出したんだ

孤独な夜の断崖に立って 飛び降りる理由あと一つだけ

そんな夜達に「くそくらえ」って ただ誰かに叫んで欲しかった

未来になれなかった あの夜に

取り立てる程不幸ではないが 涙は路銀程に支払った

僕の過去の轍を見る人よ ここで会うのは偶然じゃないさ

夢も理想も愛する人も 信じることも諦めたけど

ただ一つだけ言えること僕は 僕に問うこと諦めなかった

醜い君が罵られたなら 醜いままで恨みを晴らして

足りない君が馬鹿にされたなら 足りないままで幸福になって

孤独な奴らが夜の淵で もがき苦しみ明日も諦めて

そんな夜達に「ざまあみろ」って 今こそ僕が歌ってやるんだ
　
未来になれなかった あの夜に

ざまあみろ

Answer (score 1):

見える人にだけ見える光だ

My interpretation : "(Shadow) It's the light that only those enlightened can see."